# How to convert this date time string?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting this date time string from Sharepoint:

```
2013-01-01 08:00:00:000
```

I want to convert it to

```
2013-01-01 08:00:00 AM
```

Any ideas how to do that? Every time I try to use Date.Parse, I get an error saying the string is not a valid date time type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best option is parsing it to `DateTime` and get it's string representation with a specific format.

```
string s = "2013-01-01 08:00:00:000";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();
    // 2013-01-01 08:00:00 AM
}
```

Based on [Jon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226583/how-to-convert-this-date-time-string#comment46660529_29226605), you can use `ParseExact` as well.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-01-01 08:00:00:000",
                                  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you can format directly that `ParseExact` return value;

```
string s = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-01-01 08:00:00:000",
                               "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                   .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That was too fast! +1

Comment: While `TryParseExact` is appropriate for user-entered data, if this is expected to be correct, and it's fine for invalid data to result in an exception, it's worth at least considering using `ParseExact` instead.

Comment: Wow, such a fast answer! Thanks! It is working! I have another question though. Is there a way to find the datetime format of the string and then parse it according to that format? Because, the times might be different depending on the time zone

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, added `ParseExact` example as well. Thanks.

Comment: @user1109363: Well, you can try a number of formats, but some can be ambiguous - what does 03/04/2015 mean? March 4th or April 3rd? It's not clear what you mean about time zones - the text you've given has no indication of a time zone or UTC offset.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are Right. The dates I am getting are from a database, but according to the user's country, the dates might be in different date time format. So, the DateTimeFormatInfo we are using in the ParseExact will not be same......

Comment: @user1109363: If they're being stored in a database, they shouldn't be stored as *text* at all. If you possibly can, fix the schema so you store the date/time values *as date/time values*.